# Hover for Buefy table cell using Column meta property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

I have a Buefy table that doesn't have `b-table-columns` and uses `:data` and `:columns` to fill up with a json data points. I need to use an `@onhover` to show some other data point for a cell table.

I know I can use a `tooltip-b` for `b-table-column` like the code below:

```
<b-table-column field="id" label="ID" width="40" sortable numeric>
    <b-tooltip label="Some additional info about the status" position="is-right">
        <span class="tag is-success is-status is-small">{{ props.row.id }}</span>
    </b-tooltip>
</b-table-column>
```

but I am looking for something to not have to use `b-table-column`, because I would have to rewrite my whole table with `b-table-columns`.

I noticed a meta property that can contain anything in a buefy table column.

Should I be using something like `:meta="function(cellIndex)"`?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up rewriting the table columns with the `b-table-column` and below is working code for me:

```
          <b-table-column field="bidCondition" label="B.Cond" sortable numeric centered width="40">
            <b-tooltip :label="tooltipLable(props.row.bidCondition)" position="is-top">
              <span class="dashed-underline">{{ props.row.bidCondition }}</span>
            </b-tooltip>
          </b-table-column>
```